# How to put divs of same class under each other?

Tags: html, css

what do i do that putting class auto_box under each other. not putting side by side?

like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9fEZ.gif

html:

```
<div class="auto_box"></div>
<div class="auto_box"></div>
<div class="auto_box"></div>
```

css:

```
.auto_box {
    background: #ffffec;
    width: 173px;
    direction: rtl;
    font:16px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    color: #9d9d9d;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 8px 5px 0;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}
```

Comment: Maybe if you tell us what you want to do, we can help better. This is highly abstract. :)

Answer (score 4):

you are floating your boxes to right, so they will appear side by side. remove `float:right` so they become block level elements again:

```
.auto_box {
    background: #ffffec;
    width: 173px;
    direction: rtl;
    font:16px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    color: #9d9d9d;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 8px 5px 0;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}
```

if you want them right aligned, use `margin-left:auto` to have them stick to the right side of the screen

Answer (score 3):

For the effect you are trying achieve i would use a containing div to float the elements right, and then just display the elements as block items within that div

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DCzwu/

## html

```
<div class="right">
     <div class="auto_box"></div>
     <div class="auto_box"></div>
     <div class="auto_box"></div>
</div>
```

## css

```
.right
{
     float:right;
}
.auto_box {
    background: #ffffec;
    width: 173px;
    direction: rtl;
    font:16px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    color: #9d9d9d;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 8px 5px 0;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;

    height:30px;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kind of stuff you're doing. To my idea I would use list and style it later, even navigation. it works. for example,:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
</ul>

ul{
  list-style:none;
  line-height:40px;
}
ul li{
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  width:150px;
  padding:5px 20px; /* or something based upon need */
}
ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:/*another color*/;
  background:/*another color*/
  display:block;
}
ul li a:hover{
  color:/* another color */
  background:/* another color */
}
```

or you can place your divs in another div, then setting them up together, it's easier than setting up style for diffrent multiple divs together,

Answer (score 0):

It's the `float:right` in your CSS that is telling the browser to collect as many of the boxes on the same line as will fit. If you remove that, the boxes will go on top of each other.

If you want them right-aligned and on top of one another, you will probably have to show us the rest of your HTML/CSS context so we could advise on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try and remove float:right; from your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Add `clear: both` to `.auto_box` css

You can keep `float: right` for positioning purposes it wont it effect it

Answer (score 0):

Your css should work the way you want it to like this:

```
.auto_box {
    background: #ffffec;
    width: 173px;
    direction: rtl;
    font:16px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    color: #9d9d9d;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 8px 5px 0;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}
```